# RouteData values are valid on one page but empty on another

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-4.5, asp.net-routing

I have an app I'm building for automating the process of creating media kits when promoting a show or local event and I've hit something weird.

In my application, I have two web forms `~/KitInfo.aspx` and `~/Photo.aspx`.

In my `~\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs` I have the following boiler plate code.

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
}
```

In my `Global.asax.cs` I have the following routes registered:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    // Add Custom Routes
    RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

private void RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("MediaKitInforRoute", "Kit/{show}", "~/KitInfo.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("PhotoRoute", "Photo/{show}/{photo}/{medium}/{size}/{download}", "~/Photo.aspx");
}
```

I have a utility method for accessing the route data values:

```
public static T GetRouteData<T>(string segmentName, T defaultValue)
{
    var result = defaultValue;

    try
    {
        var textValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values[segmentName].ToString();

        result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(textValue, typeof(T));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    return result;
}
```

`KitInfo.aspx.cs` has the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var show = Utility.GetRouteData("show", string.Empty);
    var path = Server.MapPath("~/KitArchives/" + show);
    var kitPath = Path.Combine(path, show + ".kit");

    var kit = Kit.Load(kitPath);

    KitName.Text = kit.ShowTitle;
}
```

`Photo.aspx.cs` has this code in the `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var show = Utility.GetRouteData("show", string.Empty);
    var photo = Utility.GetRouteData("photo", string.Empty);
    var medium = Utility.GetRouteData("medium", string.Empty);
    var maxSize = Utility.GetRouteData("size", -1);
    var download = Utility.GetRouteData("download", 1);

    if (show.Length == 0)
    {
        SendImageNotFound();
        return;
    }
```

Navigating to `http://mediakits.server.com/kit/queen`, the page will successfully load the media kit for the show value of `queen`. Any other value will fail with expected results as the queen show is my test kit.

Navigating to `http://mediakits.server.com/Photo/queen/ShowPoster/print/900/0` fails because all of the route data is empty and `Utility.GetRouteData("show", string.Empty)` returns the default value of `string.Empty`, tripping that error check.

I'm baffled as to why it would work on one page and not the other. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have any other routes? Please post your entire routing configuration.

Comment: Those are the only two routes I have at the moment. I'm in the very early stages of this project. Though I will include Application_Start as well.

Comment: Could you post the `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes` method as well please?

Comment: Added the RouteConfig.cs code above.